# Seemingly simple MVC partial view question

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, foreach, partial-views

I am trying to display my data (images) in two columns of a table in my partial view. The code below does not seem to work as it displays each image in its own row. What am I missing?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="ULS_Site.Models"%>

<%var alternating = false;%>
<table>
<% foreach (var item in ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<image>) %>
<%{%>
<%if (!alternating) %>
<%{ %>
<tr>
<%}; %>

<td>
    <a href="<%= item.image_path %>" target="_blank" >
    <img src="<%= item.image_path %>" alt=" "  width="100"  />
    </a>
</td>
<%if (!alternating) %>
<%{ %>
</tr>
<%}; %>
<%alternating = !alternating;%>
<%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: What HTML is it generating?  From there, you can determine whether this is a browser issue or an HTML generation issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%if (alternating) %>
<%{ %>
</tr>
<%}; %>
```

EDIT: When closing the `tr`, you will need to reverse the condition.
This will not close the `tr` till the line `alternative = !alternating;` executed.

EDIT2: Also, why are you opening and closing `<%=` and `%>` on each of the line, when you are still in the code mode?

i.e Isn't there a clean way to write it?

```
<%if (alternating)
{%>
</tr>
<%}; %>
```

Comment: Great - Thanks- that worked. I'll clean up the code too on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a readability-driven approach. In addition to these other soulutions, you can also use list and display each item inside an LI tag to observe the separation of concerns rule a little better. Some standards based CSS and a sprinkle of jQuery can keep the code small and easy to read:

```
<ul>
  <% foreach (var item in ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<image>) { %>
    <li>
      <a href="<%= item.urlPath %>">
        <img src="<%= item.imagePath %>" alt="" /></li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

The CSS is can be as simple as this:

```
ul {
  width:200px; /* twice the individual LI width */
}
ul li {
  height:60px;
  width:100px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

And now that you've got raw output and structured handled, a little jQuery can take care of your alternate display needs. This will give you two vertical columns:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("li:odd").css("background-color", "#F00");
  });
</script>
```

A slightly different jQuery selector can paint colors on alternate horizontal rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will solve your problem with rendering two columns per row in the tablee.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="ULS_Site.Models"%>

<%var alternating = true;%>

<table>
<% foreach (var item in ViewData.Model as IEnumerable<image>) %>
<%{%>
<%if (alternating) %>
<%{ %>
<tr>
<%}; %>
<td>
<a href="<%= item.image_path %>" target="_blank" >    
<img src="<%= item.image_path %>" alt=" "  width="100"  />
</a>
</td>
<%if (!alternating) %>
<%{ %>
</tr>
<%}; %>
<%alternating = !alternating;%>
<%}%>
</table>
```